# How to quickly learn Python(MongoDB) from a Ruby engineer?

Tags: python, mongodb

I have developed some projects with Ruby on Rails.Now I want to quickly learn Python.Is there any good way?

I want to know some good sites,good samples,good practices.

Such as how Python connect MongoDB,etc.

Comment: Google would be a good start. This is a really vague question. Things like "How do I connect to Mongo from Python" are so trivial that they don't belong here.

Comment: This question is not a fit for SO.

Comment: MongoDB and Python? You want to learn to use the python api for mongodb?

Comment: I have voted to close due to the fact that this can be gotten with a Google search. In essence it is not really a question that can be answerable and beneficial for all, it is localised to your lack of wanting to Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best resource on python is docs.python.org, it has the CPython reference, other than that it's mostly learning the syntax, which is gonna be a little different than ruby, but is pretty simple to master.  Any of the online tutorials should give you syntactic examples.  If you have specific questions, ask those here.  One tip, if you launch python with no arguments, you'll get the repl, which will let you explore modules and objects interactively.  From there, help, vars, and dir are the three most useful functions for seeing how things work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I will read docs.